# SMBFS Mount suddenly stopped working. CIFS error

Tags: ubuntu, mount, smb

When I came in to work today, a mounted drive on our server suddenly had stopped working. In my `/etc/fstab` I have the following line:

```
//172.22.64.50/Web/  /mnt/netapp smbfs username=*****,password=******,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
```

This has been working for over a year now. Then, all of the sudden when I now try to type mount -a I get the following error:

```
root@ks-vps:~# mount -a
mount error(5): Input/output error
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I've been unable to find a solution or anything to point me in the correct direction on Google, so I’m hoping someone here can have a few tips.

Output from /var/log/syslog:

```
Nov 17 09:21:20 ks-vps kernel: [ 3118.370055] Status code returned 0xc0000001 NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
Nov 17 09:21:20 ks-vps kernel: [ 3118.370067] CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -5
Nov 17 09:21:20 ks-vps kernel: [ 3118.370850] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -5
```

Comment: Are you sure this has to do with the network mounted drive? You should try `mount /mnt/netapp` to make sure it is not some other drive generating the error. E.g. your local drive having problems and generating the error, and therefor the network mount failing as well.

Comment: Hello @Anthon. When I try that, I get this: root@ks-vps:~# mount /mnt/netapp
mount error(5): Input/output error
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question as I found the solution for my case.

It seems I suddenly needed to add workgroup to the parameters in fstab leaving the final code as following:

```
//172.22.64.50/Web/  /mnt/netapp smbfs username=*****,password=******,iocharset=utf8,workgroup=OUR-WORKGROUP,sec=ntlm  0  0
```

Comment: In my case, I suddenly needed to add sec=ntlm - I am totally sure that I didn't upgarde my Ubuntu, it just start to require that parameter one day.

Answer (score 1):

I started getting the same error messages from mount.cifs on an Ubuntu Vivid client after my samba server was upgraded from Debian Wheezy to Jessie.  I'm pretty sure this upgrade brought Samba 4 with it.  Since the upgrade, the first mount.cifs attempt after a reboot would fail exactly as you describe, but subsequent attempts would succeed.

In my case, removing winbind from the samba server solved the problem.  These bug reports are relevant:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=746229
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cifs-utils/+bug/1430259